# Plasmoid “Window List”: Increase size

Tags: kde, plasma-5, kde5

I am using the window list widget.
The window is pretty small though - I would like to make it taller.
How is that possible?
It seems there is no option to do that. Can I tinker in the code somehow to get this done?

Comment: Is your question also related to [this question you asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305461/plasmoid-excalibur-increase-size) a moment ago?

Comment: @Pizza: I do not see how it would be related. They are both about resizing something, but completely different apps (or in this case plasmoids). I would expect that the solution would be different for either.

Comment: I was just making sure - after all you've posted 3 questions one after another.

Comment: @Pizza: Ok, no problem. Yes, I moved from Kubuntu 14.04 to 20.04 recently and today I started to tackle some of the remaining issues I have with KDE Plasma 5 compared to KDE Plasma 4.